# How to avoid "failed to send operations" errors after switching to the "exactly-once" delivery strategy?

Tags: java, spring, google-cloud-pubsub

I recently tried to switch my subscriptions in GCP Pub/Sub to the "exactly-once" delivery strategy. However, I started seeing the following warnings ~10 times every 30 minutes in my application logs:

```
com.google.api.gax.rpc.InvalidArgumentException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Some acknowledgement ids in the request were invalid. This could be because the acknowledgement ids have expired or the acknowledgement ids were malformed.
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:92)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:98)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:66)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:97)
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:67)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1041)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:30)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1215)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:983)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:771)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:574)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:544)
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool$ReleasingClientCall$1.onClose(ChannelPool.java:535)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:563)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:70)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:744)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:723)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Some acknowledgement ids in the request were invalid. This could be because the acknowledgement ids have expired or the acknowledgement ids were malformed.
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:535)
    ... 17 more
```

They're immediately followed by the following `INFO` log messages in the same thread:

```
Permanent error invalid ack id message, will not resend
```

I didn't see any problems caused by these warnings, but it's a bit hard to tell because my application is processing a decent number of messages (~1000/hour). I initially thought that these warnings were just short-term "aftershocks" from switching to the "exactly-once" strategy. However, I waited for about 2 hours and they kept occurring with the same frequency, showing no sign of disappearing. I then disabled the "exactly-once" strategy and they went away immediately after. Can anyone tell me whether these warnings are dangerous, what side effects I can expect, and most importantly how I can get rid of them?

I'm using version `3.4.0` of `spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies` and `spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub`. I'm also using Spring Cloud Stream to process the incoming messages and I rely on it to automatically acknowledge the messages.

I have the following configuration set in my `application.yaml` file:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gcp:
      pubsub:
        subscriber:
          executor-threads: 15
          max-ack-extension-period: 23400 # 6 hours and 30 minutes
          acknowledgement-deadline: 600 # Maximum value
```

For context: The messages in my application represent jobs for execution, and they could take quite a while to finish - hence the 6h30m maximum acknowledgement extension period.

I also saw the following StackOverflow question:
[How to handle errors during message acknowledgement using google pubsub java library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73158039/how-to-handle-errors-during-message-acknowledgement-using-google-pubsub-java-lib)

From what I understand, the consequence of these warnings is that the messages will be redelivered to my application, but this is exactly what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the question, Alexander.

The errors you are seeing happen when the modifyAckDeadline or Acknowledgement request to the service fail because the acknowledgement id is already expired. In such cases, the service considers the expired acknowledgement id as invalid, since a newer delivery might already be in-flight. This is as-per the [guarantees](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/exactly-once-delivery#exactly-once_delivery_guarantees) for exactly once delivery. There could be a few reasons for it:

- The request was delayed due to network delays and by the time it arrived at the server, the acknowledgement id lease is already expired.
- The tasks issuing the modifyAckDeadline or Acknowledgement request is overwhelmed (high CPU/memory/network usage), leading to delay in issuing those requests.

I suggest setting [min-duration-per-ack-extension](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/spring-cloud-gcp/3.4.0/reference/html/index.html#publishersubscriber-configuration) to a high number to reduce issues mentioned above. This will help mitigate the cases where the acknowledgement id lease expired. The highest value you can set for this field is 600 seconds.

Additionally, as mentioned in the other [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73158039/how-to-handle-errors-during-message-acknowledgement-using-google-pubsub-java-lib), you should consider checking the response of your acknowledgement operations. This can be used to guide your application if it can expect a redelivery. [Sample](https://github.com/googleapis/java-pubsub/blob/c9cccd6c9b87973a7949950b8941b2a78260eab3/samples/snippets/src/main/java/pubsub/SubscribeWithExactlyOnceConsumerWithResponseExample.java).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'll check whether that eliminates the warnings and mark your answer as a solution if it does. However, I have a follow-up question, if you don't mind. Why does this only happen when using the "exactly-once" delivery strategy? The acknowledgment deadline extension mechanism exists for the "at-least-once" strategy too. The load on my application is also the same, so why do the requests fail only when "exactly-once" is enabled?

Comment: For exactly once delivery subscriptions, the acknowledgment and modifyAckDeadline requests provide the [guarantees](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/exactly-once-delivery#exactly-once_delivery_guarantees) listed. For non exactly once delivery subscriptions, those guarantees do not exist. The acknowledgment and modifyAckDeadline requests will always return OK for a well formed request (in the absence of permission/quota issues). With respect to the change referred earlier, if you see a small number of errors persisting, it would be good to check the task health around the time of the issue.